# Прерывание приложения после ConnectionTimeOut

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, исключения, requests

Всем доброго времени суток. Пишу утилиту для работы, суть в чем. Это клиент для API сервера нашего предприятия. Использую *PyQt5* и *request*. Основные функции работают, начал обрабатывать ошибки.
Код разбит на два модуля, в одном Собственно графический интерфейс. Во втором функции-обработчики для API.

Ситуация вот в чем, есть форма, где прописывается ip-адрес необходимого объекта, после нажатия кнопки вызывается метод пост, функция возвращает токен и введенный ip-адрес. Пытаюсь обработать ConnectionTimeout, дабы программа не вылетала со следующим сообщением

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Выставил таймаут, при наступлении таймаута печатается (пока что в консоли Connection timeout) но программа все равно вылетает. Может кто подсказать как быть?

Ниже привожу код модулей:

код Формы авторизации:

```
class AuthorizationForm(QWidget):
    login_data = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, Qt.Window)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bs_ip_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.bs_ip_label = QLabel("IP Адрес УСПД:")
        self.bs_ip_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.bs_ip_layout.addWidget(self.bs_ip_label)
        self.bs_ip_layout.addWidget(self.bs_ip_edit)
        self.authorization_btn = QPushButton('Авторизоваться', self)
        self.authorization_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.auth_run())
        self.auth_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.auth_layout.addWidget(self.authorization_btn)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.bs_ip_layout)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.auth_layout)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def auth_run(self):
        url_true = False
        url = self.bs_ip_edit.text()
        for ch in url:
            if ch.isdigit() or ch =="." or ch == ":":
                url_true = True
            else:
                url_true = False
                break
        if url_true:
            parse_methods.Authorization(url)
            list_value = parse_methods.Authorization(url)
            self.login_data.emit(str(list_value[0]), str(list_value[1]))
            self.close()
            return list_value
        else:
            self.bs_ip_edit.setText("Ошибка адреса!!!")
```

Код функции авторизации:

```
import requests
import requests.exceptions
import logging
import json


def Authorization(url):
    link = "http://"+url+"/auth"
    try:
        response = requests.post(link, json={'login':'admin', 'password':'admin'}, timeout=10)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        print('Connection timeout!!')
    else:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            JWT = data["WAVIOT_JWT"]
            return [JWT, url]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parse_methods.Authorization(url)              # вызов 1, результат потерян
list_value = parse_methods.Authorization(url) # вызов 2, результат сохранён
self.login_data.emit(str(list_value[0]), str(list_value[1]))
                                   ^^^                 ^^^ обращение по индексу к None
```

- Зачем вы два раза вызываете функцию `parse_methods.Authorization(url)` (первый раз теряя результат её работы)?
- В случае таймаута функция `Authorization` у вас вернёт `None` и программа упадёт, когда вы попытаетесь обратиться к `list_value[0]` и `list_value[1]`.

Договоритесь сам с собой - что должна возвращать функция `Authorization` в случае ошибки (таймаута) - и проверяйте её результат, чтобы в зависимости от него обращаться к этим полям, либо не обращаться. Можно вернуть дополнительное булевое поле, например `Success` или наоборот `HasError` - это уж как вы с собой договоритесь.

Хотя можно и ничего нового не возвращать, а просто проверять, что список не пустой и не `None`, прежде чем к нему обращаться:

```
if list_value:
    self.login_data.emit(str(list_value[0]), str(list_value[1]))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, поправил функцию, так же добавил булевы поля, и все работает)))